# Not able to install gcc in custom linux environment

Tags: linux, gcc

When I try to build gcc from source, it fails with following error:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for libatomic support... yes
checking for libcilkrts support... yes
checking for libitm support... yes
checking for libsanitizer support... yes
checking for libvtv support... yes
checking for libmpx support... yes
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/home/admin/test/gcc-6.3.0':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
```

Any way to resolve this issue..?

Comment: You know that you need a C compiler installed to build GCC?

Comment: You need to read https://gcc.gnu.org/install/ especially https://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html which makes it very clear you need a compiler already installed in order to build GCC.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I've gone through those links. How to check if there is a compiler already installed in there..?

Answer (score 2):

For install C compiler:

CentOS/Redhat

```
yum install gcc gcc-c++ autoconf automake
```

or

Debian based

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: Hey Samuel, There is no package manager available in my machine. Thanks.